# Get information from different hidden Form C++/clr

Tags: c++-cli, windows-forms-designer, msdn

I have a Windows Form application I am creating in C++/CLR Visual Studio 2012.

The goal is to have the user input values into the form named `Home Page`. Then once all the info is filled in they click a button and the `Home Page` form is hidden and then second form called `Setup Info` is shown.

The part I need help with is the info from `Home Page` needs to be accessible in `Setup Info`. To get an idea of how my files are setup this is the youtube video I followed to create my C++ Windows Form Application [Click Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpJLRfehxfY).

In my `HomePage.h`

```
// Button that will hide the Home Page Form and then show the SetupInfo Form.
private: System::Void Start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 this->Hide();
                 SetupInfo^ SetupInfo = gcnew ExcelToPPT::SeuUpInfo();
                 SetupInfo->Show();

}
```

In my `Setup Info.H`

```
// When Setup Info is loaded button1 will have the text of textbox1 from Home Page Form. 
private: System::Void SetupInfo_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    button1->Text = HomePage->Textbox1->Text;
             }
```

This is the general idea but it doesn't work. How do I get this to work?

Let me know if you need any more information.

**[EDIT]**

I am able to do this through extern global variables, but is there another way to directly access the text text boxes?

Also wen I exit out of my `Setup Information` it doesn't seem to kill my  program how do I solve this problem?

Comment: This is a standard OOP question.  You need a reference to the HomePage **object** that the user is looking at.  It is very easy to get one in your Start_Click method, it is *this*.  So pass it to your SetupInfo constructor.  Better yet, you are only need a string so no need to pass the entire form class object and expose its internals.  Use a constructor that takes a string.  Or add a public property that you can assign.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would probably be to just pass your Home Page form to the new SetUpInfo form.

```
private: System::Void Start_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->Hide();
    SetUpInfo^ setUpInfo = gcnew ExcelToPPT::SetUpInfo(this);
    setUpInfo->Show();                                 ^^^^
}
```

In SetUpInfo.h:

```
public ref class SetUpInfo : Form
{
private:
    HomePage^ homePage;

public:
    SetUpInfo(HomePage^ homePage);
};
```

In SetUpInfo.cpp:

```
SetUpInfo::SetUpInfo(HomePage^ homePage)
{
    this->homePage = homePage;
}

void SetUpInfo::SetUpInfo_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    button1->Text = this->homePage->Textbox1->Text;
}
```